# Extend a `Record<string, string[]>` with a different type of property

Tags: typescript

In Typescript the following seems like it should accomplish the creation of the desired type:

```
interface RecordX extends Record<string, string[]> {
  id: string
}
```

but this complains about:

> Property 'id' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'string[]'. ts(2411)

How can one add a property of a different type to a `Record<>` utility type?

### Details and General Case + Sample

Generally, how can one describe an object with heterogenous-value-type fixed properties but homogenous-value-type properties that are dynamically added.

S, for example given this object:

```
const a = {
   // some properties with known "hard-coded" types
   id: '123',
   count: 123,
   set: new Set<number>(),

   // and some dynamic properties
   dynamicItemList: ['X', 'Y']
   anotherDynamicallyAddedList: ['Y', 'Z']
} as ExtensibleRecord
```

So how can one define a type or interface `ExtensibleRecord` where:

1. the types and property keys of `id`, `count`, and `set` are fixed as `string`, `number` and `Set<number>`
2. the types of `dynamicItemList` and `anotherDynamicallyAddedList` and any other properties added to the object are `string[]`

I've tried many variants that I'd think might work, including:

```
type ExtensibleRecord = {
  id: string, count: number, set: Set<number>
} & Record<string, string[]>

type ExtensibleRecord = {
  id: string, count: number, set: Set<Number>
} & Omit<Record<string, string[]>, 'id'|'count'|'set'>

interface ExtensibleRecord = {
  id: string,
  count: number,
  set: Set<number>,
  [k: string]: string[]
}
```

but each seems to result in errors.

This feels like something common and obvious, but I can't find an example or reference.

### [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AzgSwEYBsICUIDGA9gE4AmAjFALxQDeAsAFBRRpkBcUKwJaSAcwA0UYgFckwLkjEBbDBBIiUEKVADKqgDwz5igHzMAvlABkUfMXJaefQct78BAbQC6hps1CRYCZOmw8QlIyACYaemZWdi5bJxFxSWk5BSVuVS5NYB0Ug2MzKAB5WTRsyxCbR3tuKpd3EQBydgaAHwbE4FaGlU6PZn5EEgAzAEMCaHhEVEwccvIAZkiWNk4au2Eo0SIJNV1UoU2ezO09gwPl5wBrWNrXG-W3Y2ZmYlRgKBGIxmWVrgaKULzBrnVhbHZcAHzEGsI5QJAQADuGhOuRI+gAFABKaFQMggJAjEoEACSiFkABk0DwuM4GgANYFQBoATQarhxIyQRGAAAtFAARfGEtAEEZYLAgACCZDIEDIlOpUFprMaAC02fkRihfFMArNguQKM8mEA)

Comment: `Record<string, string[]>` means that the `id` property, if it exists, must be a `string[]`.  You can't extend it with something that doesn't match that; you're trying to make an exception, not an extension, and TypeScript does not (yet) support that as a concrete type.  You might want to expand on your use case if you'd like a suggestion for what to do instead.  And please make sure your code is a [mcve]; right now a name collision with `Record` is obscuring your issue.

Comment: @jcalz Added more description + MWE

Comment: The reason is because TypeScript tries to do a bit more when it comes to object literal. It does that to avoid obvious errors. So if you add the dynamic property after the object literal construction, it will work.

Comment: Noting that the `satisfies` keyword can help here.

Answer (score 20):

From the official [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), it's not possible to achieve what you want:

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the
>   “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type. This is because a string index declares that
>   obj.property is also available as obj["property"]. In the following
>   example, name’s type does not match the string index’s type, and the
>   type checker gives an error:
>
> ```
> interface NumberDictionary {
>     [index: string]: number;
>     length: number;    // ok, length is a number
>     name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
> }
> ```

However, according to this [site](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html), excluding certain properties from the index signature is possible in one situation: when you want to model a declared variable. I'm copying the entire section from the [site](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

> Sometimes you need to combine properties into the index signature.
>   This is not advised, and you should use the Nested index signature
>   pattern mentioned above. However, if you are modeling existing
>   JavaScript you can get around it with an intersection type. The
>   following shows an example of the error you will encounter without
>   using an intersection:
>
> ```
> type FieldState = {
>   value: string
> }
>
> type FormState = {
>   isValid: boolean  // Error: Does not conform to the index signature
>   [fieldName: string]: FieldState
> }
> ```
>
> Here is the workaround using an intersection type:
>
> ```
> type FieldState = {
>   value: string
> }
>
> type FormState =
>   { isValid: boolean }
>   & { [fieldName: string]: FieldState }
> ```
>
> Note that even though you can declare it to model existing JavaScript,
>   you cannot create such an object using TypeScript:
>
> ```
> type FieldState = {
>   value: string
> }
>
> type FormState =
>   { isValid: boolean }
>   & { [fieldName: string]: FieldState }
>
>
> // Use it for some JavaScript object you are gettting from somewhere 
> declare const foo:FormState; 
>
> const isValidBool = foo.isValid;
> const somethingFieldState = foo['something'];
>
> // Using it to create a TypeScript object will not work
> const bar: FormState = { // Error `isValid` not assignable to `FieldState
>   isValid: false
> }
> ```

Finally, as a workaround, if it fits, you might create a nested interface (check the section "Design Pattern: Nested index signature" of [site](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html), in which the dynamic fields are in a property of the interface. For instance

```
interface RecordX {
  id: string,
  count: number,
  set: Set<number>,
  dynamicFields: {
    [k: string]: string[]
  }
}
```

Comment: Super valuable answer but the links don't work. Would be cool if you could update them :)

Answer (score 11):

If you are not using it for `class`, you can describe it using `type`:

```
type RecordWithID = Record<string, string[]> & {
  id: string
}

let x: RecordWithID = {} as any

x.id = 'abc'

x.abc = ['some-string']
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwOoEtgAsCSAIlALywIqoA8AzsMpgHYDmANFLfcwNoC6AfFABkUAN4BYAFBQomVAC52dRk0kBfSZIA2EYFAAeCuEjRZchEqNVQAhtRsMQGiXoB0siwHJrAI3genrj7wFlxe1KgAZh48TkA

Comment: — I've encountered some issues with this, so I've updated the question with more details, and (hopefully temporarily) unmarked it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Pedro's answer is 100% correct and was the start of my journey, thank you!

I wanted to discover the simplest workaround for this, and found one solution: `Object.assign()`.  It seems to be excepted from the type errors of constructing these objects manually or even when using the spread operator, perhaps as a TypeScript interop with a native JavaScript feature.

Wrapping `Object.assign()` in a factory function combined with a parallel type feels elegant to me, and perhaps it will be useful to someone else.

```js
// FACTORY WITH TYPE

// Factory uses Object.assign(), which does not error, and returns intersection type
function RecordX(
  fixedProps: { id: string },
  dynamicProps?: Record<string, string[]>
) {
  return Object.assign({}, dynamicProps, fixedProps);
}

// Type name conveniently overlaps with factory and resolves to:
// 
// type RecordX = Record<string, string[]> & {
//   id: string;
// }
type RecordX = ReturnType<typeof RecordX>;

// USAGE

// Standard use
const model: RecordX = RecordX({ id: 'id-1' }, {
  foo: ['a'],
});

// Correct type: string
const id = model.id;

// Correct type: string[]
const otherProp = model.otherProp;

// Appropriately errors with "string is not assignable to string[]"
const model2: RecordX = RecordX({ id: 'id-2' }, {
  bar: 'b'
});
```