# Typescript getting error when you have array of object and other properties in a type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object like below

```
let Obj = {
['0'] : {
 mode: 'x'
},
getMode: () => 'x'
}
```

Getting error when I create type definition like below

```
type Obj = {

[id: string]: {
mode: string
};
getMode: () => string

}
```

Getting error -- Property 'getMode' of type '() => string' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ mode: string}'. ts(2411)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), so you have to specify other type with that signature.

```
type Obj = {
  [id: string]: { mode: string} | (() => string);
}

let Obj: Obj = {
  ['0']: {
    mode: 'x'
  },
  getMode: () => 'x'
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This may be counterintuitive at first, but what you have is two definitions for `getMode` which are mutually exclusive

Within the type `Obj` you have the following:

- A generic placeholder key `[id: string]` which basically says "any key which is a string should have the following shape" (in this case `{ mode: string }`)
- An explicit key `getMode` whose value is of the shape `() => string`

As the first definition should be true for **any key that is a string**, it therefore clashes with the second definition. In other words, `getMode` is a string key and therefore satisfies the constraint `[id: string]`, meaning it must be of the shape `{ mode: string }`.

This concept (and potential workarounds) is explored in much more depth in similar SO answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208330/extend-a-recordstring-string-with-a-different-type-of-property)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a general key with `{ mode: string }` type, all properties that you define which have `string` key type (including `getMode`) should have `{ mode: string }` value type. One way of detaching `getMode` from general keys is to split your `Obj` type in two parts:

```
type GetModeType = {
  getMode: () => string;
};

type GeneralType<T extends string> = {
  [P in T as T extends "getMode" ? never : P]: { mode: string };
};
```

And then create a generic type based on their intersection:

```
type Obj<T extends string> = GetModeType & GeneralType<T>;
```

Then you can create an object based on `Obj` type:

```
const obj: Obj<"0" | "pending"> = {
  getMode: () => "hello",
  ["0"]: { mode: "zero" },
  pending: { mode: "this is pending mode." },
};
```

Notice that `Obj` type has `getMode` property with `() => string` type and the other `keys` that you want should be passed through as a generic type(string literals union).

You can read more about [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in typescript documentation.

Answer (score -1):

In Typescript `[key: string]: type` means that ALL of the object keys should be of that type. You can solve this with intersection

```
type Obj = {

[id: string]: {
mode: string
};
} & {
    getMode: () => string
}
```